# sshpass not executing in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, docker, sftp, sshpass

I have a dockerfile: (these are the relevent commands)

```
RUN apk app --update bash openssh sshpass

CMD ["bin/sh", "/home/build/build.sh"]
```

Which my dockerfile gets ran by this command

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/home <image-name>
```

and all of the commands within my bash script, that are within the mounted volume execute. These commands range from npm installs to using tar to zip up a file and I want to SFTP that tar.gz file.

I am using sshpass to automate logging in which I know isn't secured, but I'm not worried about that with this application.

```
sshpass -p <password> sftp -P <port> username@host << EOF
    <command>
    <command>
EOF
```

But the sshpass command is never executed. I've tested my docker run command by appending /bin/sh to it and trying it and it also does not run. The SFTP command by itself does.

And when I say it's never executed, I don't receive an error or anything.

Comment: show build.sh, is there any process that is running before this command and the process run in the foreground?

Comment: I have most of everything commented out at the moment, but what's left in there is `chmod +x /home/build/build.sh` 
`DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`
`TARGET="build-$DATE.tar.gz")`
and then my sshpass command

Comment: If I use scp instead of sftp I at least get a host key verification failed

Answer (score 3):

Two possible reason

- You apk command is wrong, it should be `RUN apk add --update bash openssh sshpass`, but I assume it typo
- Seems like the known host entry is missing, you should check logs `docker logs -f , Also need to add entry in for known-host, check the suggested build script below.

Here is a working example that you can try

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update bash openssh sshpass
COPY build.sh /home/build/build.sh
CMD ["bin/sh", "/home/build/build.sh"]
```

build script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "adding host to known host"
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
ssh-keyscan sftp >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts 
echo "run command on remote server"

sshpass -p pass sftp foo@sftp  << EOF
    ls
    pwd
EO
```

Now build the image, `docker build -t ssh-pass .`

and finally, the docker-compose for testing the above

```
version: '3'
services:
  sftp-client:
      image: ssh-pass
      depends_on:
        - sftp

  sftp:
    image: atmoz/sftp
    ports:
        - "2222:22"
    command: foo:pass:1001
```

so you will able to connect the `sftp` container using `docker-compose up`